# Iteration over VendTransOpen

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

This happens in Accounts Payable -> Journals -> Payments -> Payment Journal.

I choose to see the Lines for a journal and from Functions I select Settlement. I am not sure if this is the same for everyone else.

So, when clicking Settlement, VendOpenTrans opens. I need to iterate over it, and Mark the records according to the invoice of the previously selected LedgerJournalTrans field.

First of all I have to check the VendOpenTrans fields which I am not able to accomplish.

I have added the following piece of code in the init of VendTransOpen:

```
VendTrans vt; 

vt = vendTransOpen_ds.getFirst(true) as VendTrans ;


while (vt)
{           
    //Do your thing
    vt= vendTransOpen_ds.getNext() as VendTrans ;
}
```

No elements seem to be present in the vendTransOpen_ds..

Can someone give me a hint about this?

**Update 1:**

Found this :

[Understanding the Settlement Mechanism in Microsoft Dynamics AX](http://blog.mohamedaamer.com/microsoft-dynamics/understanding-the-settlement-mechanism-in-microsoft-dynamics-ax/)

and

[Automatic mark a Settlement Transactions on a Payment Journal in AX 2012](http://www.andesoft.net/automatic-mark-settlement-transactions-payment-journal-ax-2012/)

I didn't think it would be so damn difficult.. I will start digging tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things are wrong, but probably my **#2** is your main problem.

1. If you place this code in the `init` method, the query hasn't been executed yet, so nothing will be there.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa608211.aspx
2. Your code will never enter `while (vt)` because `vt` will never have a value as written because `VendTrans` and `VendTransOpen` are **two different tables** that don't support inheritance.

   The only reason `vt = vendTransOpen_ds.getFirst(true) as VendTrans ;` doesn't throw an error is because `FormDataSource.getFirst()/getNext()` returns a `Common` table record.
3. What Jan said too.

Answer (score 1):

First off, use `getFirst(0)` before using `getNext()`.
The zero indicates you want all records rather than marked.

Search, use cross reference tool, or google to get lots of references for the use of these functions.